# keep UISwitch state of a prototype cell when changing ViewControllers

Tags: uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiswitch

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass where I have connected a `UISwitch` from a custom prototype cell. (data are passed in the Table View from a previous ViewController)

When I Change view controllers the state of the `UISwitch`changes back to default
I need some way to remember the state of the switch while navigating through the app.
I have searched a few other topics, but nothing seemed to fall in my case.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myStaticSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func mySwitch(sender: UISwitch) {

    if myStaticSwitch.on {
    self.cellLabel.text = "on"
    //Do other things
    }
    else {
        self.cellLabel.text = "off"
    //Do other things
    }
}



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a model object that is used to determine the state of the UI representing it.  This object can be saved to disk, persisted with Core Data, or even synced to a remote web service.

When you next encounter a need to display any UI related to the object, you can always check its properties to determine what to show.  Your UI action method then simply updates the model representation:

```
@IBAction func mySwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
    myModelObject.enabled = myStaticSwitch.on
}
```

The UI (e.g., your table cell) then looks for changes to `enabled` and updates the `cellLabel` as needed.

Comment: I think I understand the suggested way to go, but I lack some fundamentals.
From my research, a model object is a class outside the TableViewCell, but how should I store these data there? By creating a dictionary or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485119/can-anybody-explain-mvc-in-terms-of-uitableview-when-getting-data-for-the-table is a good place to start

Comment: I did not understand much from the above link. It also was an objective-c one.
but i came closer to what I need which is shown below.
Although this time, once a Switch is changed, all other switches acquire the same state when I access the same view

Answer (score 0):

here is the code. Now I need a way to refer to each Switch separately and not as a whole.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet weak var myStaticSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func mySwitch(sender: UISwitch) {


    myStaticSwitch.on = (sender as UISwitch).on //Bool
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(myStaticSwitch.on, forKey: "autoAdjustSettings")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    myStaticSwitch.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("autoAdjustSettings")

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```