# What is the real mvc in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, model-view-controller

I have a few questions about mvc

1. Should the cell be set to Model?

Stanford University iOS8  explain mvc   View and model never talk

In smashtag demo

**Viewcontroller**

```
var tweets = [[Tweet]]()

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyborad.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TweetTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.tweet = tweets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

**UITableViewCell**

```
var tweet: Tweet? {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

func updateUI()  {
 
  tweetScreenNameLabel?.text = "\(tweet.user)"

}
```

**This is contrary to the principle of mvc ？View and model interaction**

2. UIButton in UITableViewCell

**If there is a button on the cell , its action is to remove the View on the ViewController**

**The first case**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyborad.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TweetTableViewCell

Button create and add on cell.contentView

 cell.button addTarget  on Controller
```

**The second case**

in UITableViewCell

**Button create and add on cell.contentView**

**cell.button addTarget  on Cell**

How do I get ViewViewler's View ？Through delegate ？

If my Cell has Switch, button, tap. A lot of how to deal with them Target，action

**In mvc design mode I should use the first case or the second, or better solution ？**

Comment: This might help you understand-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485119/can-anybody-explain-mvc-in-terms-of-uitableview-when-getting-data-for-the-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485119/can-anybody-explain-mvc-in-terms-of-uitableview-when-getting-data-for-the-table it will help you to understand MVC..

Comment: Thank you for your help , can you Positive answer my question?

I think the link to me did not help me much